# How to change the background color of li tag of active a element in Bootstrap tablist using css

Tags: css

I want to change the background color of active list item of the drop down menu item in css.

I tried accessing the parent using  .nav-item > a:active this is not working how can I do this?

html

```
<ul class="nav" role="tablist" #myDiv id="navdrop">
                  <!-- <li class="nav-item">
                     <a class="nav-link active" href="#all" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" onclick="addprevtext()">All</a>
                  </li> -->
                  <li class="nav-item ">
                     <a class="nav-link " href="#social" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" onclick="addprevtext()">HR</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item">
                     <a class="nav-link" href="#digital" role="tab" data-toggle="tab"
                        onclick="addprevtext()">Marketing
                     </a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item">
                     <a class="nav-link" href="#crm" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" onclick="changetext()">Customer Service</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item">
                     <a class="nav-link" href="#ticketing" role="tab" data-toggle="tab"
                        onclick="changetext()">Operations</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item">
                     <a class="nav-link" href="#coreSystem" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" onclick="changetext()">Insurance</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item">
                     <a class="nav-link" href="#dms" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" onclick="changetext()">Financial Services</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#manu" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" onclick="changetext()">Manufacturing
                           </a>
                     </li>
                     <li class="nav-item">
                           <a class="nav-link" href="#health" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" onclick="changetext()">Healthcare & Pharma

                              </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                              <a class="nav-link" href="#it" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" onclick="changetext()">IT

                                 </a>
                           </li>

               </ul>
<div class="tab-content">
                  <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane in active show" id="social">
                     <div class="row existing_connections">
                           <div class="list-type1">
                                 <ul class="list-inline">
                                 <li><a href="#"></a></li>
                                 <li ><a href="#"></a></li>
                                 <li ><a href="#"></a></li>
                                 <li ><a href="#"></a></li>
                                 <li ><a href="#"> </a></li>
                                 <li><a href="#"> </a></li>
                                 <li><a href="#">/a></li>

                                 </ul>
                                 </div>

                                 <button class="btn btn-primary lead"></button>
```

css

```
.nav-item > a:active {
        background: #003097;
    }
```

The background-color of selected li item should be changed when it is active.

Comment: What result are getting with the current code. But ensure that the `display` property of `.nav-item > a` is set to `block` so can get the effect you desire.

Comment: The `:active` pseudo class only applies as long as the user holds down the mouse button (or whatever the equivalent is using other input methods.) If this is supposed to be a Bootstrap tablist implementation (then you should have added the according tags to your question), the class `active` gets added to the `a` element of the currently active tab automatically for you, so use that to apply the desired formatting.

Comment: Yes this is bootstrap tablist, so how can add background -color to li tag of a element ? This is my question

Answer (score 0):

you have to add active class in list which is active and then give below css...

```
.nav > li.active > a{
    background: #003097;
}
```

Comment: Active changes based on the selection so in this case what can be done ?

Comment: you need to add some jQuery code so that your active class change with the active tab

Answer (score 0):

```
.nav-item a:active {
    background:#003097; 
}
```

worked for me unless u intend another behaviour